# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form

As shown here ([Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan(\frac{1}{n^2})$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848954/does-sum-n-1-infty-arctan-frac1n2-converge)), the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. It is similar to
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan\frac{2}{n^2}=\frac{3\pi}{4}$$
([Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan(\frac{2}{n^2})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094394/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-arctan-frac2n2)). A computer algebra system suggests that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan\frac{1}{n^2}=\arctan \frac{1-\cot\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\tanh\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}{1+\cot\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\tanh\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}.$$
If it's true, how can I prove it?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1091440p4855222 and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h494227p2773578

Comment: ... and here on MSE: [sum of arctangent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128357/sum-of-arctangent)